# Docker, Celery, method failing on compose

Tags: python, docker, rabbitmq, fastapi, flower

I'm trying a FastAPI based API with celery, redis, and rabitMQ as the background tasks.
when doing `docker-compose up`, the redis, rabbit, and flower parts work, I'm able to access the flower dashboard.

but it then gets stuck in the celery part.

the error:

```
 rabbitmq_1       | 2020-09-08 06:32:38.552 [info] <0.716.0> connection <0.716.0> (172.22.0.6:49290 -> 172.22.0.2:5672): user 'user' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
celery-flower_1  | [W 200908 06:32:41 control:44] 'stats' inspect method failed
celery-flower_1  | [W 200908 06:32:41 control:44] 'active_queues' inspect method failed
celery-flower_1  | [W 200908 06:32:41 control:44] 'registered' inspect method failed
celery-flower_1  | [W 200908 06:32:41 control:44] 'scheduled' inspect method failed
celery-flower_1  | [W 200908 06:32:41 control:44] 'active' inspect method failed
celery-flower_1  | [W 200908 06:32:41 control:44] 'reserved' inspect method failed
celery-flower_1  | [W 200908 06:32:41 control:44] 'revoked' inspect method failed
celery-flower_1  | [W 200908 06:32:41 control:44] 'conf' inspect method failed
```

My docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: "bitnami/rabbitmq:3.7"
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
      - "5672:5672"
    volumes:
      - "rabbitmq_data:/bitnami"

  redis:
    image: "bitnami/redis:5.0.4"
    environment:
      - REDIS_PASSWORD=password123
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - "redis_data:/bitnami/redis/data"

  celery-flower:
    image: gregsi/latest-celery-flower-docker:latest
    environment:
      - AMQP_USERNAME=user
      - AMQP_PASSWORD=bitnami
      - AMQP_ADMIN_USERNAME=user
      - AMQP_ADMIN_PASSWORD=bitnami
      - AMQP_HOST=rabbitmq
      - AMQP_PORT=5672
      - AMQP_ADMIN_HOST=rabbitmq
      - AMQP_ADMIN_PORT=15672
      - FLOWER_BASIC_AUTH=user:test
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - redis

  fastapi:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - redis
    volumes:
      - "./:/app"
    command: "poetry run uvicorn app/app/main:app --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"

  worker:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - redis
    volumes:
      - "./:/app"
    command: "poetry run celery worker -A app.app.worker.celery_worker -l info -Q test-queue -c 1"

volumes:
  rabbitmq_data:
    driver: local
  redis_data:
    driver: local
```

My celery app:

```py
celery_app = Celery(
    "worker",
    backend="redis://:password123@redis:6379/0",
    broker="amqp://user:bitnami@rabbitmq:5672//"
)

celery_app.conf.task_routes = {
    "app.app.worker.celery_worker.compute_stock_indicators": "stocks-queue"
}

celery_app.conf.update(task_track_started=True)
```

celery worker:

```py
@celery_app.task(acks_late=True)
def compute_stock_indicators(stocks: list, background_task):
    stocks_with_indicators = {}
    for stock in stocks:
        current_task.update_state(state=Actions.STARTED,
                                  meta={f"starting to fetch {stock}'s indicators"})

        stock_indicators = fetch_stock_indicators(stock)  # Fetch the stock most recent indicators
        current_task.update_state(state=Actions.FINISHED,
                                  meta={f"{stock}'s indicators fetched"})

        stocks_with_indicators.update({stock: stock_indicators})

        current_task.update_state(state=Actions.PROGRESS,
                                  meta={f"predicting {stocks}s..."})
```

The Fast API function:

```py
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
rabbit = RabbitMQHandler(host='localhost', port=5672, level="DEBUG")
log.addHandler(rabbit)


def celery_on_message(body):
    """
    Logs the initiation of the function
    """
    log.warning(body)


def background_on_message(task):
    """
    logs the function when it is added to queue
    """
    log.warning(task.get(on_message=celery_on_message, propagate=False))


app = FastAPI(debug=True)


@app.post("/")
async def initiator(stocks: FrozenSet, background_task: BackgroundTasks, ):
    """
    :param stocks: stocks to be analyzed
    :type stocks: set
    :param background_task: initiate the tasks queue
    :type background_task: starlette.background.BackgroundTasks
    """
    log.warning(msg=f'beginning analysis on: {stocks}')
    task_name = "app.app.worker.celery_worker.compute_stock_indicators"

    task = celery_app.send_task(task_name, args=[stocks, background_task])
    background_task.add_task(background_on_message, task)
    return {"message": "Stocks indicators successfully calculated,stocks sent to prediction"}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the `docker-compose`, on the `worker` section, the `command` reads:

```
command: "poetry run celery worker -A app.app.worker.celery_worker -l info -Q test-queue -c 1"
```

So essentially you are asking the worker to "watch" a queue named `test-queue`.
But on the `celery_app`, on the following section:

```
celery_app.conf.task_routes = {
    "app.app.worker.celery_worker.compute_stock_indicators": "stocks-queue"
}
```

you are defining a queue named `stocks-queue`.

Either change the `docker-compose`'s or the `celery_app`'s queue name to match the other.

Comment: changing the docker-compose to :```command: "poetry run celery worker -A app.app.worker.celery_worker -l info -Q stocks-queue -c 1"``` 

does the same thing

Comment: @yovelcohen Can you try adding the `worker` on the `depends_on` section of the `celery-flower` and inform me of what happens then?

Answer (score 0):

if you use **Docker Toolbox** on windows , so you should add port 5555 to **VM virtualBOX** network:

frist run following command on cmd:

```
docker-machine stop default
```

then open VM virtualBOX , go to *Settings >Networks > advanced>port forwarding* >add a row with port 5555 and leave name field

click OK and on cmd, run following command:

```
docker-machine start default
```